# Yii accessControl does not work. accessRules()

Tags: php, yii, access-control

I have used accessRules() many number of times but suddenly in a new project it started not working for me.

this is how i have assigned it.

```
class DefaultController extends AppController
{

    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl',
        );
    }

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('index'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('deny',
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
    /**
     * Declares class-based actions.
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            'list'=>'api.controllers.default.ListAction',
            'index'=>'api.controllers.default.IndexAction',
            'deviceSignUp'=>'api.controllers.default.DeviceSignUpAction'
        );
    }
}
```

and i have an action called list. as blow,

```
class ListAction extends RestAction
{

    public function run()
    {}
}
```

the issue is, even though i have put deny for all other actions than index. still i am able to view ListAction via **www.mywebsite.com/default/list** which should actually throw me a an error as not authenticated. what am i missing here or why accessControl does not work?

Comment: *"i have put deny for all other actions than index"* -- where did you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ symbol mean authorized users,
* mean all user.

Use typical accessControl array:

```
return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to some public actions
            'actions'=>array(<PUBLIC ACTIONS LIST>),
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow',  // allow all authorized users to some actions
            'actions'=>array(<AUTHORIZATION-NEEDED ACTIONS LIST>),
            'users' => array('@'),
        ),
        array('deny', // deny all other actions
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),              
);
```